# Issues using touchesBegins

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I have a button. I want to change the image on initial touch. If the touch is less then 1 seconds, I want it to do X. If the touch is longer then 1 second, I want it to do Y.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle this. A UIButton has proved troublesome so I thought I could do it with `UIGestureRecognizers` or `touchesBegin:`

Initial thought was have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to detected just a quick tap to do X, and use a `UILongTapGestureRecognizer` to handle a longer press to do Y.

The issue is a `UITapGestureRecognizer` does not flag `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, it only ever sends a notice for `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnd`.

So I decided trying a combination of overridding the `touchesBegin:` and `touchesEnd:` methods and using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // change image
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // do X
    // change image to original image
}

-(IBAction)longPressDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    DLog(@"fired");

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Do y
        // change image to original image
    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {

    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    }
}
```

If the `UILongPressGestureRecognzier` fires, it cancels the inital `touchesBegan:` (does not fire `touchesEnded:` method).

But I have run into the issue where the `touchesBegin:` method is slow to fire. There is a .5 second delay in the method being fired. What baffles me, if I use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with a `longTap.minimumPressDuration = 0`, it fires instantly.

This is with in the program where I need it to be. Playing around with it in a dummy area, the `touchesBegins:` fires instantly as well.

What could cause it to lag within the program?

Is there a different way I can obtain the desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you could use a timer and a Long Press Gesture Recognizer

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didRecognizeLongPressGesture:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0;
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

...

```
- (void)didRecognizeLongPressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    static NSTimer *timer = nil;

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.1 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        //change the image here
    }
    else if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        if ([timer isValid])
        {
            //the user has pressed the button less than a second
            [timer invalidate];
            timer = nil;
        }

    }

}

- (void)changeImage:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;

    //change to the other image here
}
```

Comment: Ok, this works. I removed the `touchesBegins:` code and the long press responds immediately and the timer works perfectly. Still not sure why the `touchesBegins:` method is so sluggish but the gesture is repsonsive (I have a sneaking suspicion it has to do with my use of `NSLayConstraints`, but that is a task to figure out another day). Thank you!